# Oracle SQL - how dates are compared

Tags: sql, oracle, date, comparison

I am new with SQL in general and with Oracle in particular.

I created a collection of dates => **dates** consisted of **date (i)**

I have a table **table** with columns **date** and **revenue**.

When I make query

```
select sum(revenue) from table where date between date(i) and date(i+1)
```

I cant get correct number => the values is less than correct one.

When I make

```
select sum(revenue) from table where date between to_date(date(i),'dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date(date(i+1),'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

the different story => I receive null value.

Only

```
select sum(revenue) from table where date>=date(i) and date<=date(i+1)
```

works well.

But why?

Comment: The default format is yyyy-mm-dd so when you are converting it you get a different result

Comment: One more question - when I made a query and then see results in output, dates are presented as 'dd-mm-yyyy'. That is confusing. So, the default processing format is 'yyyy-mm-dd', but the default display format can be different. Am I right?

Comment: @SO ReadytoHelp Thx, it helped

Comment: Do you get the difference when you run `select date from table where date>=date(i) and date<=date(i+1)`, resp. `select date from table where date between date(i) and date(i+1)`

Comment: What is the data type of column `date` and collection `date`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: you should un-delete your answer. The useless conversion from a date to a varchar and back to a date using `to_date()` on `date` value is almost certainly the reason for this.

Comment: The _display_ format is up to the SQL client you are using. As dates do not have a format, they can be displayed in any format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables in your collection are already dates and you're converting them again into dates (that's something you should never do). When you convert a DATE into a DATE, the variable is previously converted into a string by Oracle using the default date format mask. You can see yours with:

```
SELECT value
FROM nls_session_parameters
WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
```

In my case, my date format is `DD-MM-RR`. So, if I convert the date 01-01-2015 into a date again, it would get converted like this:

```
1. It will be implicitly converted into a string using the DD-MON-RR mask. I would get 01-01-15.
2. Then, it will convert the string 01-01-15 into a date using the mask you provide (dd-mm-yyyy). In this case, to_date('01-01-15','dd-mm-yyyy') will return 01-01-0015.
```

That might be the cause why you're not getting any results in your query:

```
select sum(revenue) from table where date between to_date(date(i),'dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date(date(i+1),'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

If you used the 'dd-mm-rrrr' mask instead, it will convert the string 01-01-15 into 01-01-2015 and your query might return somethin. I don't know, it will depend on the dates in your collection.

Comment: Four digit year `yyyy` format is the four digit year format. `rrrr` also accepts two values only but this seems to be not the case.

Comment: `to_date(to_date(..))` make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I'm just explaining why he's not getting any results in one of his querys because that's what he's asking. Of course, that's unnecessary. Have you guys read my answer before downvote it? And I think it might be related to the format mask he's using. Let him decide if that's the case or not.

Comment: Well you state: "*it will might work fine*" and then _repeat_ that useless `to_date(to_date())` call. Changing the format of the `to_date()` does not "fix" the wrong (implicit) conversion from a date to a varchar back to a date (I didn't downvote)

Comment: The to_date(to_date()) is useless, sure. But he's studying how dates works, he's not facing a real problem. That's why he's doing that useless conversion and I just said that using that mask it might work, because it worked for me. If his implicit mask has 2 year digits, the rrrr mask will do the trick.

Comment: You repeat the fact that `to_date(to_date())` is useless but yet you suggest to still use it. I don't understand that. Your "solution" is **still** subject to implicit data type conversion that is influenced by the NLS settings of the _client_ running the statement.

Comment: Yess, I repeated the to_date(to_date()) is useless and I DON'T suggest to use it, I just wanted to let him know about the difference between the YYYY and RRRR masks. That's all! I should have written a comment instead of an answer because my answer is not complete and didn't talked about the implicit varchar conversion,

Answer (score 2):

Why do you convert a `DATE` value into a `DATE` value?

When you do `to_date(date(i),'dd-mm-yyyy')` then following happens:

1. Date value `date(i)` is converted implicitly to a string using the current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` format.
2. Then this string is converted back to a `DATE` value using the format `dd-mm-yyyy`

So, if **by chance** your current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` format is equal to `dd-mm-yyyy` then your query will work.

Or, in order to make it working perform `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd-mm-yyyy';` before you run your query. However, it is a stupid and useless idea to convert a DATE value into a DATE value.

Comment: This is the correct answer and the downvote is unjustified

Answer (score 0):

Date values also contain the time. Therefore, two dates are only equal when they contain the same day and the time is also the same.

So when you compare "17-11-2015 07:15:00" with "17-11-2015" it will not be equal.

This would account for the number of rows being returned to be less than expected in your statement:

```
where date between date(i) and date(i+1)
```

date (plus time) might be larger than date(i+1) even though the day is the same.

If you are not interested in the time component use the trunc() function to eliminate the time component. So you could write:

```
select sum(revenue) from table where trunc(date) between date(i) and date(i+1)
```

(I take it that date(i) does not have a time).